# multiple levels of associated db objects to YAML

Tags: ruby, serialization, yaml

I need to create a 'List' object from the following db tables. I've already done this in a rails/datamapper application, but now I have a need to get specific lists into and out of a db through YAML.

```
List
  Categories
    Items
      Item choices
```

e.g. given a list identifier, pull the initial list, the categories for that list, the items for those categories, and the choices for those items into some object, then output as a yaml file.

My first step is output a specific list to yaml, this shouldn't be a unique situation and I'm sure others have solved it before. From reading I'm guessing I need a multilevel hash of some sort, but all I've been able to do so far is get list and category...i.e. this is a bit out of my range right now, and I'm only working from the command line.

I'm asking for two things really to assist in sharpening my skill set:

- guidance on working with a multiple level, nested hash situation to properly serialize an object for yaml, given a series of associated db tables
- if there is an easier way that someone has already solved.

Comment: I have one solution below, but would like to keep this open for a bit more in hopes of getting alternate input. I'd like to see how this or similar issue has been solved by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The included to_json ([doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)) method already allows you to easily nest related records, and choose what you want to output :

```
List.all.to_json(:only => {}, :include => { 
                   :categories => { :only => {}, :include => { 
                     :items => { :only => :your_attribute_name }
                   }
                 })
```

The next step is to convert it to yaml :

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your_json).to_yaml
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This looks promising....I'm using DataMapper and dm-serializer and right now I'm looking for a way to include below a second level.

Comment: This is definitely helpful and more useful that what I had been doing.